# Flink 1.4.2 SQL Maps?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am currently using **Flink V 1.4.2**

If I have a POJO:

```
class CustomObj{
  public Map<String, String> custTable = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, String> getcustTable(){ return custTable; }

  public void setcustTable(Map<String, String> custTable){
      this.custTable = custTable;
  }
}
```

I have a `DataStream<POJO> ds = //from some kafka source`

Now I do `tableEnv.registerDataStream("tableName", ds);`

And I want to run

```
tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE custTable['key'] = 'val'");
```

When I try running this I get the error:

`org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Type is not supported: ANY`

What can I do about this and how can I fix it?